How to write a test if the argument defines a type
This is not a pydantic question, but to explain why am I asking: pydantic.TypeAdapter() accepts (among many others) all the following type definitions as its argument and can create a working validator for them:
int
int|str
list
list[str|int]
typing.Union[int,str]
typing.Literal[10,20,30]

Example:
>>> validator = pydantic.TypeAdapter(list[str|int]).validate_python

>>> validator([10,20,"stop"])
[10, 20, 'stop']

>>> validator([10,20,None])
(traceback deleted)
pydantic_core._pydantic_core.ValidationError: ...

I want to make a test if an argument is a such type defition.  How do I write such test?

I started with isinstance(arg, type) for simple types like int or list
then I added isinstance(arg, types.GenericAlias for list[str] etc.
then I realized it does not recognize int|str (which itself behaves differently than typing.Union[int,str]). Also the Literal[] is not recognized ... I'm probably on a wrong track.


I think you can use typing.get_origin combined with isinstance(x, type) like you already mentioned:
import typing
def defines_type(x): return isinstance(x, type) or typing.get_origin(x) is not None

Testing it out we see our defines_type function returns True for all these:
int
int|str
list
list[str|int]
typing.Union[int,str]
typing.Literal[10,20,30]
type(None)
Point # here Point = collections.namedtuple('Point', ['x', 'y'])
Vector # here Vector = list[float]
VectorExplicit # VectorExplicit: typing.TypeAlias = list[float]
typing.Optional[int]
collections.OrderedDict

and False for all these
1
'a'
[10,20,'stop']
None
[10,20,None] 
Point(10, -2) # here Point = collections.namedtuple('Point', ['x', 'y'])
typing.Union # Interesting case! not a valid type or type annotation (I assume this behaviour is what you want)
{'a', 'b'}

